# How to solve Illegal string offset ['id'] in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question but I don't know how to solve my problem. Every time I try to correct my error I fail. My code is:

```
if (isset($_GET["comment"])) {$id = $_GET["comment"];}
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = {$id['$id']};";        
$get_comment = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Can anybody correct the code to not show an error anymore and tell me what did I wrong?

Comment: why do you have {$id["$id"]}? Just use {$id}

Comment: Obligatory "SQL injection alert, learn about prepared statements" comment here. [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) is awesome.

Comment: unless $_GET['comment'] is an array just use {$id} in your query. Needless to say, be aware that your code is really vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: $id is array for my page id so i mean like this ..."WHERE id = {$array_name['$page_id']};";

Comment: @expresso: please check Niet the Dark Absol's solution posted below, it's way better thank everything posted until now :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$id = isset($_GET['comment']) ? $_GET['comment'] : 0;
$query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = " . intval($id);
```

The use of `intval` will protect you from SQL injection *in this particular case*. Ideally, you should learn [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) as it is extremely powerful and makes prepared statements much easier to handle to prevent *all* injections.

---

An example using PDO might look like:

```
$id = isset($_GET['comment']) ? $_GET['comment'] : 0;
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = :id");
$query->execute(array("id"=>$id));
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // for a single row
// $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // for multiple rows

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: +1 for finding an alternative way to prevent sql injection in such a case.

Comment: There's also `mysqli_real_escape_string` which would work on string input too. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @735Tesla Yes - however when using that it will be important to put quotes around the value. Enough people forget that, that people have in fact blindly downvoted my `intval`-based answers (on other questions) simply because "OMG you need quotes!"

Comment: As you've acknowledged, this is the quick and dirty approach. The answer has been well-received but you clearly favour a different method, so perhaps it would be useful to also include a short example showing how to do this using PDO. It might also be interesting to see how it looks compared to my answer, which uses the procedural style mysqli functions.

Comment: @TomFenech Sure. Edited in.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should prevent injestion.

```
if (isset($_GET["comment"])){
  $id = (int)$_GET["comment"];
}
```

Notice, `$id` contanis `int`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = {$id}";
```

Comment: I thought that it is `string`, but then i noticedt it is `int` so i edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `$id` is an integer and you only want to make the query if it is set, here's how you could do it using prepared statements, which protect you from MYSQL injection attacks:

```
if (isset($_GET["comment"])) {
    $id = $_GET["comment"];
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $get_comment);
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        // use $get_comment
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Most of these functions return a boolean indicating whether they were successful or not, so you might want to check their return values.

This approach looks a lot more heavy duty and is arguably overkill for a simple case of a statement containing a single integer but it's a good practice to get into.

You might want to look at the object-oriented style of mysqli which you might find a little cleaner-looking, or alternatively consider using PDO.